# Can android system clear the cache when the application runs?

Tags: android, caching

I work on android application. In onCreate I check and extract some data to cache from assets. However I noticed that when is application paused and then resumed back (after minute or so) then sometimes is cache empty. System cleared the cache when application was in background (Activity was not finished) and I must in onResume event check the cache and extract data again. This leads me to crazy thought...can android OS clear the cache (in some weird situation) when application runs and is in foreground?

This happens on Samsung s20fe with android 13

Comment: "extract some data to cache from assets" -- what is your precise definition of "cache"? If you mean "extract some data from assets to a global variable" or something like that, then yes, [your process can be terminated while it is in the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle).

Comment: I have in assets fonts and database of fresh data for every version which must be extracted. I cant connect to database while is in apk. Fonts have 15MB, i can read them directly from assets, but much faster it is from storage.

Answer (score 0):

The [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-remove-cache) said:

> Caution: When the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete these cache files to recover space. So check for the existence of your cache files before reading them.

So I think the cache file may be removed by the system if it's not in use, no matter whether the app is running or not.

Comment: Thank you. So cache is probably not best place for storing exrracted asset files which are too big to be extracted frequently. Then I must extract them to permanent storage and i must manage deletion